# Need help in understanding the loop speed with timeit function in python

Tags: python, timeit

I need help in understanding the %timeit function works in the two programs.

Program A

```
a = [1,3,2,4,1,4,2]
%timeit [val + 5 for val in a]
830 ns ± 45.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Program B

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,3,2,4,1,4,2])
%timeit [a+5]
1.07 µs ± 23.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

My confusion:

1. µs is bigger than ns. How does the NumPy function execute slower than for loop here?
2. 1.07 µs ± 23.7 ns per loop... why is the loop speed calculated in ns and not in µs?

Comment: probably because of some initial overhead created by numpy that would be dwarfed by its increase in computation speed on much larger lengths of a, I am guessing tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy adds an overhead, this will impact the speed on small datasets. Vectorization is mostly useful when using large datasets.

You must try on larger numbers:

```
N = 10_000_000


a = list(range(N))
%timeit [val + 5 for val in a]

import numpy as np
a = np.arange(N)
%timeit a+5
```

Output:

```
1.51 s ± 318 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

55.8 ms ± 3.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```